# change view in react native (0.5)

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have 2 views and I want to move from the first one to the second one without using **createStackNavigator**

There´s no need to use navigation because the first view is just a welcome screen

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Welcome!</Text>
                <Button
                    title="sign In"
                    onPress={() => navigate('SignInScreen')}
                />

            </View>
        );
    }
}

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Sign In screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeScreen
```

the error I´m getting is

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')
```

thank you.

Comment: the `navigation` is passed to your component when the component became part of `*Navigator`, is `HomeScreen` part of any `navigator` like `StackNavigator` or `TabNavigator`?

Comment: is not. the code I have is the one I pasted. I guess that´s why is undefined right?

Comment: Yes, you are trying to access `navigation` which is not available in your component. For simple screens, you can use conditional rendering based on state variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag on state.  When you click the button on `HomeScreen`, it will change the flag to true, which will allow the conditional statement to call the `SignInScreen` to be rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: false,
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return this.loggedIn ? (
      <SignInScreen />
    ) : (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome!</Text>
        <Button
          title="sign In"
          onPress={() => this.setState({ loggedIn: true })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Sign In screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: interesting approach. is this the only way? let´s say I have more screens like welcome > sign in > profile (there´s no need to have a navigation to go back to welcome or sign in screens when you are signed in) do you still recommend flags for that case? thanks for your help!

Comment: you can use react-navigation to create a stack navigator to handle other screens after signing in, then upon successful signin, you would navigate to the stack navigator.  Then the home screen of the stack would be whatever your first 'main' component is after you sign in.  

I created a simple app where my signin is the first page of the stack, and the back button that goes back to the signin page is used as a signout button.

Comment: Can I move loggedIn outside of HomeScreen so I can use it there and in other views? thanks!!

Comment: state is component based so taht `loggedIn` variable is only accessible inside of the HomeScreen component.  you could use redux to make state persist through the app, but thats on the more complicated side if your not already familiar with it.  You can also use another item built into react-native called `AsyncStroage`.  Its like localStorage in a browser.  AsyncStorage will persist on the device until the app is deleted off the device.  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html